# Neural Network Extreme Memory Usage

Tags: machine-learning, pytorch

Most of my work with neural networks has been with smaller models, but I wanted to try using Facebook's `dino_vits8`. My machine does not have a graphics card, but it does have 32 GB of RAM, as well as 128 GiB of swap.

When running the model, it quickly allocates all of the available memory and the process is killed.

The size of the input tensor is:
`torch.Size([1, 3, 1920, 2560])`

And my input code:

```
import torch
import torchvision

model = torch.hub.load('facebookresearch/dino:main', 'dino_vits8')

model.eval()

image = torchvision.io.read_image('../Images/1_0.png')

image = torch.unsqueeze(image, 0)

print(image.shape)

image = image/255.0

model(image)
```

When running without Swap, the error provided is:
`RuntimeError: [enforce fail at alloc_cpu.cpp:75] err == 0. DefaultCPUAllocator: can't allocate memory: you tried to allocate 141561446424 bytes. Error code 12 (Cannot allocate memory)`

Is this amount of memory usage expected, and if so, are there any measures that I can take to reduce it?